# Explaination - Image segmentation using feed forward neural network by clustering algorithm

Tags: image, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, cluster-analysis

Image segmentation using feed forward neural network by clustering algorithm.

I know the machine learning algorithms. (which algorithm goes what)

I wanted to know that what the following piece of line implies. Best would be an example. I want to know that how a person will go through this project?

Answer (score 0):

Image segmentation is the act of finding features in an image. Those features can then be analysed by a separate algorithm.

For example, if you had an image of a dog chasing a ball in a park, image segmentation would break up the pixels of the image into features such as the ball, the dog, the sky, ground and any trees. Once you have those features, you can ignore the ones you're not interested in.

Neural networks can be used to perform "k-means" clustering or edge detection to find your features. A feed forward network in this case would be a multi-layer perceptron (MLP).

As an aside, I would not use a feed forward network for this task as there are much simpler algorithms that can perform image segmentation. Instead, neural networks usually act on the result of image segmentation.

References: [Wikipedia on Image Segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation)